# Сортировка строк с числами и символами

Tags: c#

Есть массив строк

```
List<string> s = new List<string>{"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15c","15b","150","15a"};
```

Если мы просто вызываем

```
s.Sort();
```

То он сортирует их как
1
10
11
12
13
14
150
15a
15b
15c
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Как сделать чтобы он выдавал интуитивно человеческую сортировку? Т.е. работала и сортировка по string, но в первую очередь - еще и по значению числа. Т.е. правильный вывод в данном случае будет

1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15a,15b,15c,150;

Я понимаю, что можно написать компаратор, который, вероятно, ищет цифры внутри строки, если находит их, проверяет, где больше, а если строку - то по алфавиту, но как это конкретно реализовать?

И тут скорее вопрос, может быть что-то подобное уже реализовано? Может есть какой нибудь StringComparsion.NumericFirst, который просто аргументом в сортировку передается и сортирует так, как рассортировал бы это человек?

Comment: Напишите свой компаратор.

Comment: Зовется это вроде как `Alphanumeric sorting`, [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645306) неплохой пример на SO. Другие примеры думаю теперь без труда сами найдете, как говориться на свой вкус и цвет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот моя попытка. На гениальность не претендую, потому что сам в регулярках слабоват, возможно есть способ проще.

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> s = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15c", "15b", "150", "15a" };
    s.Sort(new MyComparer());
        
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", s));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
public class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+)([a-z]?)");
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        Match m1 = regex.Match(x);
        Match m2 = regex.Match(y);
        int a = int.Parse(m1.Groups[1].Value);
        int b = int.Parse(m2.Groups[1].Value);
        if (a < b)
            return -1; 
        if (a > b)
            return 1;
        return string.Compare(m1.Groups[2].Value, m2.Groups[2].Value);
    }
}
```

Опять же, здесь нет никакого защитного программирования, если будете использовать этот вариант, позаботьтесь о случаях, когда строка имеет неправильный формат.

Вывод в консоль

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15a, 15b, 15c, 150
```

---

Вариант без `int.Parse`.

```cs
public class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private readonly Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+)([a-z]?)");
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        Match m1 = regex.Match(x);
        Match m2 = regex.Match(y);
        string num1 = m1.Groups[1].Value;
        string num2 = m2.Groups[1].Value;
        if (num1.Length < num2.Length)
            return -1;
        if (num1.Length > num2.Length)
            return 1;
        int cmp  = string.Compare(num1, num2);
        if (cmp != 0)
            return cmp;
        return string.Compare(m1.Groups[2].Value, m2.Groups[2].Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Регулярки и парсинг чисел не нужны - достаточно длин. 2. Буква после чисел не нужна. 3. Защищаться не от чего - регулярка гарантирует корректность. 4. Вряд ли он хочет сортировку с учётом регистра.

Comment: @Qwertiy почему парсинг чисел не нужен? Без него оно выдаст 1 10 11 12 13 14 , а надо учитывать возрастание.

Comment: @Potion, число, в котором больше цифр, больше числа, в котором меньше цифр (исключение - лидирующие нули). А при равенстве длин лексикографическое сравнение даёт тот же результат, что и арифметическое.

Comment: @Potion я если честно не понял, что имел в виду модератор, да я и не стремился выдать идеальное решение, а скорее просто рабочее, быть может он и прав, и данное решение не оптимально, но зато есть, с чего начать.

Comment: Модератор имел ввиду, что 555 больше чем 88 понятно и без парсинга, т. к. в первом длина 3, а во втором 2. Когда длина одинаковая, то и алфавитная сортировка справится